# Determine if 'put' operation actually executed in putIfAbsent method of ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I want to know whether 'put' operation actually executed in putIfAbsent method of ConcurrentHashMap.

This is what I want:

```java
if(map.putIfAbsent(Key,Value)){//Clearly this is wrong
  return true;
}

//other operation

return false;
```

Comment: You have a misspelling in your return statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Map#putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) will return null if no associated key exists or the value for the key is null. Otherwise it will return the existing value.

```java
V resultOfPut = map.putIfAbsent(key, value);

if (resultOfPut == null) {
    // was able to put
} else {
    // was not able to put, value already exists
}
```

Comment: You could also just change the condition to: `if (map.putIfAbsent(Key,Value) != null)` for the least amount of effort. :p

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl (awesome name btw) Yeah very true, I just defined the local variable to make it more descriptive and clear (arguably less clear haha).

Comment: nice one,thank you~ I saw java doc "the previous value associated with the specified key, or null if there was no mapping for the key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with the key, if the implementation supports null values.)"